# How to download a message, store it and recreate it in a different folder?

Tags: delphi, imap, indy

I'm using Delphi 2006, Indy 10 (ver. 4957), IMAP4.

I would like to download an e-mail message, store it and some weeks later I would like to recreate it in a different folder. (It is sort of archiving and restoring it, so simple moving between folders does not work as I will delete the original message.) I download the message, store it, then make a copy of it with `AppendMsg`.

It works until that point when I check the target Temp2 folder, where most of the messages contain

> This is a multi-part message in MIME format

```
unit Mail_Test;

interface

uses
  Windows,
  Messages,
  SysUtils,
  Variants,
  Classes,
  Graphics,
  Controls,
  Forms,
  Dialogs,
  StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class( TForm )
    memLog: TMemo;
    btn1: TButton;
    procedure btn1Click( Sender: TObject );
  private
    procedure Log( LogMsg: string );
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  IdIMAP4,
  IdMessage,
  IdExplicitTLSClientServerBase,
  IdSSLOpenSSL;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btn1Click( Sender: TObject );
var
  IMAPClient: TIdIMAP4;
  UsersFolders: TStringList;
  OpenSSLHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  res: Boolean;
  i: integer;
  inbox, currUID: string;
  cntMsg: integer;
  msg, msg2: TIdMessage;
  BodyTexts: TStringList;
  flags: TIdMessageFlagsSet;
  fileName_MailSource, TmpFolder: string;
begin

  IMAPClient := TIdIMAP4.Create( nil );
  try
    OpenSSLHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create( nil );
    try
      IMAPClient.Host := 'imap.gmail.com';
      IMAPClient.Port := 993;
      IMAPClient.Username := '....@gmail.com';
      IMAPClient.Password := '....';

      if Pos( 'gmail.com', IMAPClient.Host ) > 0 then begin
        OpenSSLHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv3;
        IMAPClient.IOHandler := OpenSSLHandler;
        IMAPClient.UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS;
      end;

      try
        res := IMAPClient.Connect;
        if not res then begin
          Log( '  Unsuccessful connection.' );
          exit;
        end;

      except
        on e: Exception do begin
          Log( '   Unsuccessful connection.' );
          Log( '  (' + Trim( e.Message ) + ')' );
          exit;
        end;
      end;

      try
        UsersFolders := TStringList.Create;
        try
          res := IMAPClient.ListMailBoxes( UsersFolders );
          if not res then begin
            Log( '  ListMailBoxes error.' );
            exit
          end;
        except
          on e: Exception do begin
            Log( '  ListMailBoxes error.' );
            Log( '  (' + Trim( e.Message ) + ')' );
            exit;
          end;

        end;

        Log( 'User folders: ' + IntToStr( UsersFolders.Count ) );
        for i := 0 to UsersFolders.Count - 1 do begin
          Log( '  [' + inttostr( i + 1 ) + '/' + inttostr( UsersFolders.Count ) + '] Folder: "' + UsersFolders[ i ] + '"' );
        end;

        IMAPClient.RetrieveOnSelect := rsDisabled;
        inbox := 'INBOX';
        Log( 'Opening folder "' + inbox + '"...' );
        res := IMAPClient.SelectMailBox( inbox );
        cntMsg := IMAPClient.MailBox.TotalMsgs;
        Log( 'E-mails to read: ' + IntToStr( cntMsg ) );

    //    res := IMAPClient.RetrieveAllEnvelopes( AMsgList );

        msg := TIdMessage.Create( nil );
        msg2 := TIdMessage.Create( nil );
        BodyTexts := TStringList.Create;
        TmpFolder := 'c:\';
        res := IMAPClient.CreateMailBox( 'Temp2' )
        try

          for I := 0 to cntMsg - 1 do begin

            Log( '  [' + inttostr( i + 1 ) + '/' + inttostr( cntMsg ) + '] E-mail...' );

            IMAPClient.GetUID( i + 1, currUID );

            Log( '(Downloading message...)' );
            IMAPClient.UIDRetrieve( currUID, msg );

            fileName_MailSource := TmpFolder + 'Log_Mail_' + currUID + '.eml';
            msg.SaveToFile( fileName_MailSource, false );

            // In the final version I will delete the original message 
            // so I have to recreate it from the archived file

            msg2.LoadFromFile( fileName_MailSource );

            res := IMAPClient.AppendMsg( 'Temp2', msg2, msg2.Headers, [] );
          end;
        finally
          FreeAndNil( msg );
          FreeAndNil( msg2 );
          FreeAndNil( BodyTexts )
        end;

      finally
        IMAPClient.Disconnect;
      end;
    finally
      OpenSSLHandler.Free;
    end;
  finally
    IMAPClient.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Log( LogMsg: string );
begin
  memLog.Lines.Add( LogMsg );
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Is it your assertion that the messages *shouldn't* say they're multipart messages in MIME format? What *problem* are you having?

Comment: Of course they are multipart messages but the uploaded messages become a mess. For example one of the messages opened in an email client is shown like this:  

"This is a multi-part message in MIME format

--kQoHZj9xrCzNf77TupjT4sJi4sO2i=_bzh
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="US-ASCII"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Disposition: inline

Hi Rondald," 

So it seems that the simple savetofile + loadfromfile + appendmsg sequence does not work. I would like that part corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the version of `AppendMsg()` that lets you specify alternative email headers.  In just about every situation I can think of, you will never want to do that (I don't even know why TIdIMAP4 exposes that functionality).

The reason is because `AppendMsg()` saves the `TIdMessage` to an internal `TStream` and then sends the email body from that `TStream` to the server.  If you specify alternative headers, they will be sent as-is and not match the header data that was used to create the email body.  Most importantly, the MIME boundary used to separate MIME parts within the email body will not match the boundary specified in the headers that are actually sent to the server, which would account for the symptoms you are seeing.  That boundary value is randomly generated by `TIdMessage` whenever it is encoded, so it is not available in the `TIdMessage.Headers` property prior to calling `AppendMsg()`.

So, with that said, I strongly suggest you change your code to set the `AAlternativeHeaders` parameter of `AppendMsg()` to nil (or use the overloaded version of `AppendMsg()` that does not have an `AAlternativeHeaders` parameter at all) so that `AppendMsg()` will send the actual headers that `TIdMessage` itself generates when it is encoded prior to upload:

```
res := IMAPClient.AppendMsg( 'Temp2', msg2, nil, [] );
```

Or:

```
res := IMAPClient.AppendMsg( 'Temp2', msg2, [] );
```